# Fancybox : Back to top after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox v2.1.5 to show my register form.

The form is a bit long and I would like the page to scroll to top after clicking submit button to show the errors or the success message.

The problem is that I know how to "back to top" on a simple page with Jquery but this isn't working with Fancybox.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
```

Here is my code :

```
<head>
...
</script>
/* FANCYBOX */
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding     : 8,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        fitToView: false, 
        maxWidth: "100%"
});
</script>
...
</head>
<body>
<form id="RegisterForm" name="RegisterForm">
...
<button name="Register" type="submit" id="Register">
    Register
</button>
</form>
<script>
$('#RegisterForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'register.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#result').html(data);
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                }
        });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help and support :)

Comment: try placing `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400)` inside the fancybox `afterClose` callback

Comment: Thx. But the problem is that the Ajax doesn't close the fancybox. It's just updating the content. It's closing it only if there is no errors.